# Mootools Classes and Binding

Tags: class, variables, binding, scope, mootools

I am having trouble accessing both the Class and the current element. How can I have access to both the current element and the Class?

```
// Class stuff above
fuction1 : function () {
  myelements.addEvent('click', this.function2);
},
function2 : function () {
  // "this" is the element from function1
  this.getParent('div')

  // now I need to call another function
  // But since the scope is the element, I get an error
  // If I bind function two,
  // how can I gain access to the element?
  this.function3();
}
//Class stuff below
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way. Note that the event is already passed to the method:

```
var Foo = new Class({

    initialize: function() {
        this.elements = $$('li').addEvent('click', this.click.bind(this));
    },

    click: function(e) {
        console.log(this); // Foo Class
        console.log(e.target); // the clicked this.elements item
    }

});
```

And a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AtUgd/

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
FooBar = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        this.element = $('foobar');
        this.element.addEvent('click', function(e) { this.foo(e) }.bind(this));
    },
    foo: function(e) {
        console.log( $(e.target) );
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks very similar to something I was trying earlier. Someone else suggested that instead of passing the "e" to the function, to set it to a class variable such as "this.element" and using that in the second function. Is there a reason you chose not to do that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can write this as `this.element.addEvent("click", this.foo.bind(this))` - no need for the anon func. event will be passed on automatically.

Comment: This wouldn't work though if there were multiple elements correct?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `e.target` isn't always that element you really expect (the one you binded).

It's an element that is clicked so if your binded element contains something inside, click event will get [bubbled up](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) and it will fire, but you will have wrong element in `e.target`

If you want to pass event binded element to one of your class methods you can do it like this:

```
var self = this; // 'this' is class reference
elements.addEvent('click', function(e){
    self.myClassMethod(this, e); // now 'this' is clicked element
});
```

Now you got the right element passed to your method and ready to manipulate on.